# travis-ci karma singleRun

Tags: karma-runner, travis-ci, karma-jasmine

On my local machine I want `npm test` to watch files and re-test on change, so I use `singleRun: false` in `karma.conf.js`.

On travis-ci this causes a timeout error. How do I override the `singleRun` option for travis-ci environment only?

Answer (score 2):

Given that the cli can also be used to enable/disable singleRun, adding "--no-single-run" to the karma cli run *might* override the config file...

Alternately, given the karma.conf.js is a Javascript file, can you write the setting of singleRun as a function (e.g. which detects one of the Travis environment variables) and spit out "false" or "true" appropriately?

Answer (score 1):

I use the following solution (inspired by @palfrey). Travis runs will have `CI=true` set as an environment variable.

Use node's `process.env` function to set a local var to the value of `CI` (or false if unset), then use this as the value for `singleRun` in the config:

karma.conf.js

```
const ci = process.env.CI || false

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    singleRun: ci,
    ...
 }
}
```